# Adding field to table without path to table (python)

Tags: python, arcpy

I want to add a field to my table in the FieldCalculator.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.AddField_management("veg8", "test", "TEXT")
```

An error message occured doing this and I figured out that I need to set a path to my table
Like this for instance

```
C:\\user\\...
```

But, since I work in the Modelbuilder and the Model will be running on other computers, the path to the table will be a different one and I dont want to update all my paths everytime I run the model on a different computer. Is there a way to tell python to use the table to which the FieldCalculator is "connected"?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Can you clarify.  You want to add a field in the FieldCalculator or Python Window?  Also, if you're in the Field Calculator (inside the Attribute Table), why not just use the menu there to add a field?

Comment: I am in the ModelBuilder. We are building a model that shall run with different data and no furhter modification (or at least as less modifications in the model as possible). So feed it data, the model processes it, and then have some output. Thats why I cannot do in the Attributestable!
I give the field calculator a shapefile as an input and want the fieldcalculator to process it in the modelbuilder. Since I am doing further calculations after adding the field, I want to add the field in the FieldCalculator.

Comment: fieldcalculator does not add field, it runs a python script that evaluate a value within an existing field. What you show is an arcpy sample for a standalone script, and then you mention modelbuilder, so this is confusing. For adding a field in modelbuilder, use AddField.

Comment: Yep. I wrote that part into the FieldCalculators 'CodeBlock'. I thought thats how you tell the FieldCalculator to look the upcoming instructions/syntaxes in the arcpy library up. 
I thought I can do it without the tool AddField right before I do calculations with the Calculator (which is python as well).

Comment: FieldCalculator is meant for calculating within a field, there you may use python or VB code to perform some kind of calculation.  If you want to Add a field through model builder drag the "add field" tool to the window, or use a stand alone python script. Your python code as it stands in your question does not belong in the field calculator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will learn some Python and try to include a script into the modelbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [in-line variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_inline_variable_substitution/002w0000001t000000/), in ModelBuilder, so you can update all your paths simultaneously.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll be gone until the end of next week but afterwards I'll have a look. Or I learn a little bit of python and write a script myself which I include into the modelbuilder :)